# I want to know about C Library Configuration

Tags: c

The C Standard Library is independent of any operating system and system.
So, why use the input/output functions from the standard library?
Unix-specific POSIX system calls exist. Windows-specific input/output system calls exist.
Don't standard library functions eventually call system calls internally? Is this just for portability?

Comment: "Don't standard library functions eventually call system calls internally" --> It is implementation defined how a standard library implementation achieves the correct functionality.  Note: no system calls are _required_ by the standard.

Comment: The C library allows you to write a program that runs on both Unix and Windows, rather than having to write OS-specific code for each.

Comment: So yes, it's for portability.

Comment: so, standard library doesn't call system function?

Comment: What the other guys said.  Additionally, most flavors of Unix (including Linux) document the C standard library in `man` section 3. Try `man 3 printf` for example. So calling the C library _is_ making a system call.  If you restrict the definition of "system call" to traps into the kernel, that set of calls in all OSs I've seen is much more limited than the C library.

Comment: Generally C libraries aren't configured, as what they provide is specified as "must be present", etc.  But they can be installed or removed, and sometimes systems keep track of where they are, and those systems can be configured.

Comment: @LiamJackson "so, standard library doesn't call system function?" -- The answer is "it depends"  Some library functions don't need to access more than the CPU and already allocated RAM.  These functions are unlikely to require system calls, provided that memory-fenced RAM access on the hardware doesn't require a system call. Other functions want to access hardware that requires an operating system driver.  Those functions generally do use a system call; but, there are also operating systems where one can "go around" the operating system, in which case those functions might not need system call

Comment: "I want to know about C Library Configuration" hmm.. to me it's unclear what you are asking... configuration of what?

Comment: Further, the text mainly addresses IO functions but libc is much more than that...

Answer (score 1):

The API presented by the C standard library is uniform between operating systems, well, uniform provided all the "unspecified" parts of C roughly align (like the size of int).

The implementation of the C standard library is not independent of the operating system.  Basically the implementation consists of the compiled source code the provides the API, and that compiled code matches the CPU / machine instruction sets, and possibly other items specific to the hardware bus width, supporting chip sets and other actual hardware details.

So, programming against the C API helps your program be "more portable" but that doesn't mean that any specific implementation of the C API is portable.  Finally, there are lots of small details that aren't specified in detail, or are allowed to vary between platforms (like byte order, size of int, and so on).  So even a program written against the standard C API might not work correctly on another machine, unless you write code that accommodates and reacts to the parts of the C API that might differ between platforms.

POSIX is basically a standard that eventually became incorporated into most C development environments.  It is designed to provide a single API to program against for multiple UNIX platforms for items that lie outside of the core C language.  There are POSIX implementations for Windows too, but Microsoft's historical offerings are notorious for not actually working correctly.

Yes, these APIs (if available) are implemented with code that eventually performs operating specific calls, and is presented in "machine code" that is very specific to the CPU instruction set.  There are dozens of CPUs out there, and each major platform has its own matching compiler and matching C API libraries, if the C language is available.

The C language and API is there for portability, but portability isn't it's primary reason for existing (and there are lots of small corner cases where the same code isn't portable across all platforms unless it is written a certain way.)  The primary reason it's there is not portability, it is because if the language features weren't consistently available across all platforms, then you wouldn't have "one C language" that could be used on multiple machines, you would have "many C-like languages, where each supported item would have to be checked" meaning you might know C on your development platform, but not know C on another platform.

As for the libraries, there are many libraries that might be absent in a typical machine, and when developing, you generally have to use a dependency checker to ensure the library is present (and sometimes the correct functions are available in the library) before successful use of the machine for development.  Autoconf, for example, has m4 macros that can be configured to check if a library is present before compiling the programs.

Comment: For even more portability, many systems don't run directly on the CPU, but instead provide a "software CPU" or emulator.  These systems can even erase most of the observable differences in how code execute on different hardware.  Java's JVM is an example, where source code is compiled into "byte code" which is a JVM's machine code.  The JVM is platform specific, and ensures that regardless of the CPU / hardware involved, the byte code is handled identically even if the CPUs don't support the operations they carry out.